# what does this piece of code mean in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I came across the following code:

```
let timeoutHandler;

clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
timeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {...});
```

This is an overly simplification since the original code is contained in a Vue application as follow:

```
public handleMultiSelectInput(value): void {
            if (value === "") {
              return;
            }

            clearTimeout(this.inputTimeoutHandler);
            this.inputTimeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {
                axios.get(`${this.endpoint}?filter[${this.filterName}]=${value}`)
                  .then(response => {
                      console.log(response);
                  })
            }, 400);
        }
```

Does this mean this is some kind of cheap-ass debounce function? 
Could someone explain what this exactly means.

Comment: Well, you guessed it right. It's a cheaper version of debounce function.

Comment: ... especially if it is bound to an input control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a debounce function, which is when we wait for some amount of time to pass after the last event before we actually run some function.

There are actually many different scenarios where we might want to debounce some event inside of a web application.

The one you posted above seems to handle a text input. So it's debouncing the input, meaning that instead of fetching that endpoint as soon as the user starts to enter some character into the input, it's going to wait until the user stops entering anything in that input. It appears it's going to wait 400 milliseconds and then execute the network request.

The code you posted is kind of hard to read and understand, but yes, that is the idea of it.

I would have extracted out the network request like so:

```
const fetchData = async searchTerm => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${this.endpoint}?filter[${this.filterName}]=${value}`);
  console.log(response.data);
}

let timeoutHandler;
const onInput = event => {
    if (timeoutHandler) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandler);
  }
  timeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {
    fetchData(event.target.value);
  }, 400);
}
```

Granted I am just using vanilla JS and the above is inside a Vuejs application and I am not familiar with the API the user is reaching out to. Also, even what I offer above could be made a lot clearer by hiding some of its logic.

Comment: Accepted the answer an the right one although @Praveen has given a faster answer but didn't post an answer